# What's wrong with this if-statement in php

Tags: php

```
if ((isset($post["username"]) && isset($post["password"])) && (!empty($post["username"]) && !empty($post["password"])) && ($post["username"] == "something" && $post["password"] == "something"))
{

}
```

> Error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in [file_name here but I rather not expose the file path and name]

I know it is kinda complicated but what's wrong with this if-statement as I receive the error above. Although I checked several times.

Comment: should be the errors on the lines before.

Comment: Why do you use both isset() and empty()? To simplify statements like these I usually use some kind of token to know when the formular is submitted. By doing that I only have to validate the actual content of username and password

Comment: The only lines before the if-statement is this `<?php

$post = $_POST` just 2 lines of code.

Comment: @Muncken `isset()` is used to whether the variable has been set but it could be an empty variable still, `empty` is used to check whether it is empty or not. So far if all these 2 conditions are satisfied, then check actual `username` and `password`

Comment: You're missing your semicolon on $post = $_POST.  It should be $post = $_POST; and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: Braveyard: Hence my comment about using a token instead (i.e. token == "send"). I to this to simplify my if-statement exactly to minimize the amount of these long statements.

Comment: @Muncken Would you please give me an sample code for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error `unexpected T_IF` indicates that the if is unexpected, meaning there is an error BEFORE the if.  Probably a dropped semicolon.  Check above the if and you should find your problem.

Comment: Yeah, funny me. I am using Vb.NET and forgetting to use "semicolon". Thanks by the way.

Comment: No problem.  I'm primarily a c/PHP dev, but I've used VB.Net a bit in school and I would ALWAYS put a semicolon on the end of the lines in VB.

Comment: Yeah but Vb.NET doesn't allow me to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion I might make (for the sake of other people who might have to edit your code later) is to break down the if statement:

```
$valuesAreSet = isset($post["username"]) && isset($post["password"]);
$areNotEmpty = !empty($post["username"]) && !empty($post["password"]);
$areValid = $post["username"] == "something" && $post["password"] == "something";

if ($areSet && $areNotEmpty && $areValid) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I kinda like this way :) Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing a semicolon in the line that precedes the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you aren't missing any semi-colons.

Also just to check, you did want to use the variable `$post` and not `$_POST` right?